# How to update dynamically created t-SQL in C#?

Tags: c#, t-sql

I have a `SQL` where `Where` and `AND` clause are created dynamically. What I want is, update this SQL based in some condition.

**Actual Query:**

```
var sql = $@"SELECT DISTINCT
                  c.Name AS CallCenterd
                  LTRIM(RTRIM(s.Name)) Name,
                  d.DNIS,
                  s.ScriptId
           FROM CallCenterScript s WITH (NOLOCK)
                LEFT JOIN CallCenterScriptLine sL WITH (NOLOCK) ON sL.ScriptId = s.ScriptId
                INNER JOIN CallCenterDNIS d WITH (NOLOCK) ON d.ScriptId = s.ScriptId
                INNER JOIN CallCenter c WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.Id = s.CallCenterId
           WHERE {callCenterIdClause} 
           AND ({keywordClause})
           ORDER BY {sortParameters.ToOrderBy()}";
```

**Which generates this,**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       c.Name AS CallCenterd,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(s.Name)) Name,
       d.DNIS,
       s.ScriptId
FROM CallCenterScript s WITH (NOLOCK)
     LEFT JOIN CallCenterScriptLine sL WITH (NOLOCK) ON sL.ScriptId = s.ScriptId
     INNER JOIN CallCenterDNIS d WITH (NOLOCK) ON d.ScriptId = s.ScriptId
     INNER JOIN CallCenter c WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.Id = s.CallCenterId
WHERE c.Id = 5 
AND    (s.Name LIKE '%McAlisters%'
      OR d.DNIS LIKE '%McAlisters%'
      OR s.Script LIKE '%McAlisters%'
      OR sL.Line LIKE '%McAlisters%')
ORDER BY DNIS ASC
```

**What I want is,**

```
if(condition matched)
{
    SELECT DISTINCT
           c.Name AS CallCenterd,
           LTRIM(RTRIM(s.Name)) Name,
           d.DNIS,
           s.ScriptId
    FROM CallCenterScript s WITH (NOLOCK)
         LEFT JOIN CallCenterScriptLine sL WITH (NOLOCK) ON sL.ScriptId = s.ScriptId
         INNER JOIN CallCenterDNIS d WITH (NOLOCK) ON d.ScriptId = s.ScriptId
         INNER JOIN CallCenter c WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.Id = s.CallCenterId
    WHERE (s.Name LIKE '%McAlisters%'
          OR d.DNIS LIKE '%McAlisters%'
          OR s.Script LIKE '%McAlisters%'
          OR sL.Line LIKE '%McAlisters%')
    ORDER BY DNIS ASC
}
```

Should I use something like, `sql = sql.Where(x => someLogic)`?

Comment: Whatever you do, that string is a nightmare.  I hope this isn't active in an externally-exposed production environment. The injection risk here is nuts.  Is this meant to fill a `DataTable`?  Where is this data going?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just overwrite the variable `sql` in the if.

Better yet just have an `if else` for `callCenterIdClause`.  Use `1 = 1` for when you don't want `c.Id = 5`.

Comment: `callCenterIdClause => "1 = 1"` Lowest effort, lowest risk, cleanest solution

Comment: Make sense. This is what I wanted.